# IIS logparser - Count distinct from cs-uri-query?

Tags: iis, sql, logparser

I need to count how many DIFFERENT MAC´s that have accessed my IIS webserver and have a state value of 1.

The "MAC" adress and the "state" value are in the actual query (cs-uri-query)

So the log can look like this (only the cs-uri-query field are shown):

```
mac=00-20-c2-41-7e-b6&state=1&div=10
mac=00-20-c2-41-7e-b6&state=1&div=10
mac=00-20-c2-41-7e-b6&state=0&div=10
mac=00-10-c3-41-7e-b7&state=1&div=10
```

In this case the LogAnalyzer should count=2. 2 times have DIFFERENT MAC´s visited with the state of 1.

Can someone help me with the SLQ to use with LogAnalyzer?

Comment: I deleted my answer since I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking (and I was trying to do more than logparser SQL can handle...).  Can you add a sample data set and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Thx...i will change my initial post so it´s more obvious what i am looking for. I´ll be right back with a changed text.

Comment: Hope you can understand it better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
select count(distinct extract_value(cs-uri-query, 'mac'))
from *.log
where extract_value(cs-uri-query, 'state') = '1'
```

You might hve to adjust field names depending on your log format.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work great! The "extract_value" function? seems to do it. Is that a native SQL function?

Comment: No, EXTRACT_VALUE was designed exclusively for the cs-uri-query scenario, to extract values out of key-value pairs in strings.